# XML Serialization or Plain XML to Stored Procedures for saving session objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

I was reading the XMLSerializer class. This is in context of serializing the session object in XML and send it to the Stored Procedure to save it to the database.

So the above process includes the Serialization conversion and then sends to the stored procedure for further processing. Or it can just create xml like below and send to the stored proc to save the details in database.

```
<Root><Row></Row></Root>
```

Comment: So what's your question? Also, your title is not very informative. There are probably a dozen questions iwth the same title, and they're all about something different.

Comment: Although your question is about Xml, if you are talking about ASP.NET session objects, they can be also serialized into strings (TextWriter or Stream as output) using the *LosFormatter* class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.losformatter.aspx). I believe that's what ASP.NET uses internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLFormatter` can be used while serializing

Answer (score 0):

For SQL server it will be anyway plain text,so format should be chosen considering your application needs. I think than using XML Formatter is more convenient.